# Unsure if the following WHERE statement is valid when trying to return dates from a table based on dates in a different table

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have written an sql query, and I've tested it such that, I've come to the conclusion that the WHERE statement is giving me issues.

Scenario:
I have a table which contains a list of dates. Lets call this table, table A.

I have a second table which contains table 2 columns, **"Start Date"** and **"End Date"**.

What I want to do is, filter the dates in table A which contains a list of dates based on the dates that exist between the **"Start Date"** and **"End Date".**

For instance, if **"Start Date"**- 01/01/2017 and **"End Date"** is 01/02/2017, then I want to return the dates between the **Start Date** and **End Date** from table A which contains all the dates.

Here is the SQL Query I have written:

```
$query = "SELECT ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy, ec.Date, c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge, ec.User, st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas,
st.StartDate, st.EndDate, st.TargetElecCharge, st.TargetGasCharge, ua.Username
FROM energyconsumption ec INNER JOIN
useraccount ua
ON ec.User = ua.id
INNER JOIN
energytarget st
ON st.customerID = ua.id INNER JOIN
Charge c
ON ec.ChargeID = c.id
INNER JOIN
energytarget st ON
st.energyID = ec.id
WHERE ec.Date = ec.Date >= st.StartDate AND ec.Date <= st.EndDate
GROUP BY  ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy,   c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge, st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas, st.StartDate, st.EndDate, ua.Username ";
```

**Question**
How do I write a WHERE statement that filters for dates in table A based on the dates that exist between the Start Date and End Date in table B.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried to use the BETWEEN statement to resolve the statement, this is what I did:

```
$query = "SELECT ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy, ec.Date, c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge, ec.User, st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas,
st.StartDate, st.EndDate, st.TargetElecCharge, st.TargetGasCharge, ua.Username
FROM energyconsumption ec INNER JOIN
useraccount ua
ON ec.User = ua.id
INNER JOIN
energytarget st
ON st.customerID = ua.id INNER JOIN
Charge c
ON ec.ChargeID = c.id
INNER JOIN
energytarget st ON
st.energyID = ec.id
WHERE ec.Date BETWEEN ec.Date >= st.StartDate AND ec.Date <= st.EndDate
GROUP BY  ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy,   c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge, st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas, st.StartDate, st.EndDate, ua.Username ";
```

Also, could there perhaps be an issue with the statement "

```
INNER JOIN
    energytarget st ON
    st.energyID = ec.id"
```

which is just above the WHERE statement

Comment: `WHERE ec.Date = ec.Date >= st.StartDate AND ec.Date <= st.EndDate` looks wrong to begin with.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hi, haha yeah I just took a shot at it. Not sure how else to approach this problem

Comment: You need to use the keyword `BETWEEN`. You are also grouping which may be giving issues. I am at work but can look at this later if a solution is not found yet.

Comment: @Shawn Cheers mate! I'll give your suggestion a go.

Comment: @Shawn Hi, unfortunately that has not worked. The output message I'm getting is "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Can you provide your schema on your tables? It might be easier to see a better solution with those. Also the relationships one to many, one to one, etc

Comment: Please, post the actual query.

Comment: Why are you joining with the same table twice, but different criteria? Can you post some sample table contents and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an error in JOIN clauses:

There are two join clauses with the same alias:

```
    INNER JOIN energytarget st ON st.customerID = ua.id 
    INNER JOIN energytarget st ON st.energyID = ec.id

SELECT ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy, ec.Date, c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge, 
       ec.User, st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas, st.StartDate, 
       st.EndDate, st.TargetElecCharge, st.TargetGasCharge, ua.Username
FROM energyconsumption ec 
     INNER JOIN useraccount ua ON ec.User = ua.id
     INNER JOIN energytarget st ON st.customerID = ua.id 
     INNER JOIN Charge c ON ec.ChargeID = c.id
     INNER JOIN energytarget st ON st.energyID = ec.id
WHERE 
    ec.Date = ec.Date >= st.StartDate AND ec.Date <= st.EndDate
GROUP BY ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy, c.ElecCharge, 
         c.GasCharge, st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas, 
         st.StartDate, st.EndDate, ua.Username
```

Comment: Ah ok, so should I just used a different alias? Would that resolve that particular problem?

Comment: Ok, I've changed "st" to "stt". Problem is still persisting unfortunately

Comment: energytarge is used twice, which one is used to select dates?